AD / SYSVOL Version Mismatch on Local Admin Policy (Restricted Group settings)
I am going to crazy about 1 weeks. I following many documents and solution for this but no way.
I am trying to suppress BUILTIN\Administratos Group members on domain computers with a policy which i wrote in the Primary Domain Controller. For this process, add a group in Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Restricted Groups ss added below.
Restricted Groups Looks Like
Link this Group Policy to the whole domain. After that i restart my pc.
When pc opend and logged in i check Administrators group on my pc Local Users and Groups with lusrmgr.msc . I see nothing changed, old default users still there and new ones not added. So Restricted Group Policy not affected.
Than i run Gpresult /h C:\Users\Xuser\Documents\gpresultreport.html /f command in command promt than i check report output. SS added below;
Gpresultreport.html
Gpresultreport.html
I search over internet about AD / SYSVOL Version Mismatch and trying some solutions but no help.
Strange thing is, when i use gpupdate /force command sometimes succesfully added users to to BUILTIN\Administrators group sometimes not.
Also sometimes this added users gone and BUILTIN\Administrators group turn to default by self.
Also second strange thing is generally if you restart the pc 2 times succesfully added desired users to BUILTIN\Administrators group
I double check all other group policies for using Restricted Groups using. This setting cannot be used in any other policy i am sure.
Also i check PDC and ADC repplication status. All thing ok. Wh have no repplication issues.
DCs Rep Status
------- EDIT 2 ------
Third weirdness happen now. When i restart the pc than look last policy added with Gpresult command. I see desired Policy applied but desired users not added to Restricted Group like below screenshots;
Policies applied succesfully
But 5 users missing in Restricted Group.
The part that makes me think is that sometimes the problem happens and sometimes it doesn't. I really couldn't get out of the situation.

What about sysvol replication status? That's what seems damaged.

hi @GregAskew i check with Repadmin /replsummary and repadmin /showrepl commands both command outputs are OK. There is no error.

I added Dcs Rep Status screenshot to main question.

repadmin is for Active Directory replication status. Windows is telling you that the version in AD does not match the version in SYSVOL. That's bad. You can do a simple check by connecting GPMC to the other DCs and checking the policy settings.

Hi @GregAskew I solve the AD / SYSVOL Version Mismatch issue editing the Gpt.ini file in ADC Server i think. I added some weird thing to the main question paragraph under EDIT 2.

You should investigate why SYSVOL is not replicating... It may occur again.

After editing Gpt.ini file in ADC same issue occured again. repadmin commands show no error on repplication. How can i check SYSVOL issues?

--SOLVED--
After a week of research and headaches, I identified the problem and fixed it.
The problem was in DFSR Replication between PDC and ADC.
A log with event ID 4012 was found in the DFS Replication logs under the Windows Event Logs of the ADC server. I'll leave this below.
The DFS Replication service stopped replication on the folder with the following local path: C:\Windows\SYSVOL\domain. This server has been disconnected from other partners for 135 days, which is longer than the time allowed by the MaxOfflineTimeInDays parameter (60). DFS Replication considers the data in this folder to be stale, and this server will not replicate the folder until this error is corrected. 
 
To resume replication of this folder, use the DFS Management snap-in to remove this server from the replication group, and then add it back to the group. This causes the server to perform an initial synchronization task, which replaces the stale data with fresh data from other members of the replication group. 
 
Additional Information: 
Error: 9061 (The replicated folder has been offline for too long.) 
Replicated Folder Name: SYSVOL Share 
Replicated Folder ID: 8510D957-8458-4FD3-BEE1-C1A6D11AD669 
Replication Group Name: Domain System Volume 
Replication Group ID: B2FEB9F5-B50A-4AB4-A4BE-3818012D1174 
Member ID: 25287B81-07D3-4300-A23F-BB2072D10589

When I looked with below command, I saw state 5 on the ADC server. This also indicated an error.
For /f %i IN ('dsquery server -o rdn') do @echo %i && @wmic /node:"%i" /namespace:\\root\microsoftdfs path dfsrreplicatedfolderinfo WHERE replicatedfoldername='SYSVOL share' get replicationgroupname, replicatedfoldername,state

The state values ​​can be any of:
0 = Uninitialized
1 = Initialized
2 = Initial Sync
3 = Auto Recovery
4 = Normal
5 = In Error

Then I checked the MaxOfflineTimeInDays value for DSFR Replication on all DC servers with the following command.
For /f %i IN ('dsquery server -o rdn') do @echo %i && @wmic /node:"%i" /namespace:\\root\microsoftdfs path DfsrMachineConfig get MaxOfflineTimeInDays

The result was 200 days for PDC and 60 days for ADC. Therefore, since my problem exceeded 60 days (135 days), DFSR Replication was no longer possible.
With the following command, I increased the DSFR MaxOfflineTimeInDays value on the PDC and ADC to 250 days and restarted the DSFR Replication service on both servers.
$i = gwmi -namespace root\microsoftdfs -query 'Select * FROM DfsrMachineConfig'
# increase the MaxOfflineTimeInDays to more than just a day
$i.MaxOfflineTimeInDays =[uint32]250
$i.Put()
Restart-Service -Name DFSR -Verbose

Then I checked by running the command below again and confirmed that the state was 4 for both DCs.
For /f %i IN ('dsquery server -o rdn') do @echo %i && @wmic /node:"%i" /namespace:\\root\microsoftdfs path dfsrreplicatedfolderinfo WHERE replicatedfoldername='SYSVOL share' get replicationgroupname, replicatedfoldername,state

When I looked at the status of the GPOs on the PDC and ADC, all GPOs seemed to be synchronized without any errors.
After that, I ran Gpupdate /force on the entire domain and confirmed that all machines received the updated policies.
I hope it helps someone who has the same problem.
I wish everyone good luck in their work :)
